# Java Arraylist/List error

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, arraylist

I have marked the line thats giving me trouble

```
private void EditButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

DefaultListModel PatientListModel = new DefaultListModel();

```
for (Patient s : PatientList) {
    int AccNum = Integer.parseInt(IDTextField.getText());

    if (AccNum == s.getAccountNumber()) {

        s.setName(NameTextField.getText());
        s.setAge(Integer.parseInt(AgeTextField.getText()));
        s.setAddress(AddressTextField.getText());
        String PatientSex = "";

        if (MaleRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            PatientSex = "Male";
        }

        if (FemaleRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            PatientSex = "Female";
        }

        s.setSex(PatientSex);
        s.setPhone(PhoneTextField.getText());
        ArrayList<PatientCondition> PatientConditions3 = new ArrayList();
  ===>      PatientConditions3 = (ArrayList<PatientCondition>) ConditionsJList.getSelectedValuesList(); //error here
        s.setConditionsList(PatientConditions3);
        PatientInfoLabel2.setText("Patient Details Updated");

        for (Patient f : PatientList) {
            PatientListModel.addElement(f.getAccountNumber() + "-" + f.getName());
        }

        PatientJList.setModel(PatientListModel);
        UpdateAllViews();

        //       
    }
}
}
```

the error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$EmptyList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the question but you shouldn't start your variable names with capitals, follow java guidelines it is very important.

Comment: @resus whilst yes it would be better to stick to the correct naming conventions. There is still nothing wrong with it that will stop the code from working. I would just advice the benny to have a read of this http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm as using the correct naming convention will help you big time in the future when maintaining code. Even if you are just messing around with the code it would be good practice to start doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the error message is pretty informative. You can't do that cast.

You should redefine your `PatientConditions3` to be of type `List<PatientCondition>`. It is good practice to code against the interface `List` instead of a specific implementation, like `ArrayList`.  Also, you should rename it to follow Java naming conventions:

```
List<PatientCondition> patientConditions3;
```

If you need to convert the received `List` to for example an `ArrayList`, you can create a new one with the elements of the received `List`:

```
patientConditions3 = new ArrayList<PatientCondition>(ConditionsJList.getSelectedValuesList());
```

Comment: But I need to make it an arraylist to use it?

Comment: @benny: Added info on how to get an `ArrayList` from the received `List`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Collections.emptyList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29) returns a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) reference casting which to an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is illegal.

Try changing this

```
ArrayList<PatientCondition> PatientConditions3 = new ArrayList();
```

to this

```
List<PatientCondition> PatientConditions3 = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: How do I cast a list to arraylist to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the method declaration of the method `ConditionsJList.getSelectedValuesList` specifies that it returns a `List`. You cannot count on it that that list is going to be an `ArrayList`.

Change the type of your variable `PatientConditions3` to `List` instead of `ArrayList`. Also, it is not necessary to create a new `ArrayList` and assign that to `PatientConditions3` if you immediately assign to `PatientConditions3` again; you then create that `ArrayList` for nothing, it's immediately thrown away.

```
List<PatientCondition> PatientConditions3 = ConditionsJList.getSelectedValuesList();
```

Another remark: According to common Java coding conventions, you shouldn't start variable names with an upper-case letter. Call it `patientConditions3` instead of `PatientConditions3`. (And that applies ofcourse to all your other variables as well).

Answer (score 0):

A `List` variable cannot be cast to an `ArrayList` if there is not actually a `ArrayList` behind it. In most cases you should rely on Interfaces for your variables to allow maximum flexibility

```
List<PatientCondition> PatientConditions3 = ConditionsJList.getSelectedValuesList();
```

Concerning type safety: Only cast if you are **really** sure the object to cast is an instance of the target type. check that with `instanceof` before you cast.

Comment: I need to cast it back to an arraylist though to use it?

Comment: if you change the type of PatientConditions3 to List<PatientCondition> then there is no need to cast. most of the methods ArrayList provides to client code are implementations of the List interface so in most cases List as type for variables is all you need

Answer (score 0):

When you have there `ConditionsJList.getSelectedValuesList();` you get a collection (or List<> if this sounds better to you) of some values. And you just need to cast them to be `PatientCondition`..So you should have there something like:
`PatientConditions3 = (PatientCondition) ConditionsJList.getSelectedValuesList();`

Of course PatientConditions3 must be `List<PatientCondition>` ...

Answer (score 0):

this does a cast for you if it's an ArrayList, otherwise the ArrayList is empty:

```
ArrayList<PatientCondition> patientConditions3 = (ConditionsJList.getSelectedValuesList() instanceof ArrayList<PatientCondition> ? ((ArrayList<PatientCondition>) ConditionsJList.getSelectedValuesList()) : new ArrayList<PatientCondition>());
```